# how can access conact from application?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, addressbook

I am developing a project that access the contact from my application. But I cant access  contact from my app. Can anyone help me accessing contacts from my app, if it is possible?

Comment: post the code you have already.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by using [Address Book Programming Guide for iPhone](http://www.inf.furb.br/~dalton/disciplinas/ebook/manuais/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone.pdf)